# Перестаёт грузиться css после добавления параметра к url

Tags: css, symfony, маршрутизация

В `routing.uml` есть маршрут

```
category:
    path:     /category
    defaults: { _controller: MainBundle:Client:showCategory }
```

ведущий на экшн, который рендерит страницу, к которой подключены стили таким способом: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="bundles/MainBundle/css/category.css">`. При этом всё работает, при переходе на `/category` стили успешно грузятся.
Появилась задача передавать в маршрут параметром id-категории. Делаю это по примеру. В `routing.uml`:

```
category:
    path:     /category/{id}
    defaults: { _controller: MainBundle:Client:showCategory }
    requirements:
        id: '\d+
```

И теперь, после перехода на `/category/1` контент страницы отображается, но без стилей.
Что нужно исправить, чтоб вернуть css?

Версия Symfony 3.1

Comment: Решением проблемы оказалось использование другого формата задания пути к css: `href="<?php echo $view['assets']->getUrl('bundles/MainBundle/css/category.css‌​') ?>"`

Answer (score 1):

Возможно у тебя просто из-за доступа по другому урл меняется текущее местоположение. А твой путь к css вставлен как "относительно текущего документа". Поэтому стилей и не видно.

Попробуй сделать ссылку на стиль, используя путь относительно корня сайта (если это, конечно же, не запрещено сделать по какой-либо причине). А именно добавить слэш в начале пути и прописать полный путь до файла со стилями.

```
<link href="/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: Слеш в начале не помогает ((
И этот путь и есть полный, начиная от коневой директории `web\`.
Но всё равно спасибо.